# Dotenv variable is undefined

Tags: nestjs, dotenv

I have one module (auth module) where I register JwtModule:

```
JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60m' },
    }),
```

Register function looks like this: `static register(options: JwtModuleOptions): DynamicModule;`

JwtModule is defined in node_modules (jwt.module.js)

```
let JwtModule = JwtModule_1 = class JwtModule {
    static register(options) {
        console.log(options);
        console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        return {
            module: JwtModule_1,
            providers: jwt_providers_1.createJwtProvider(options)
        };
    }
```

In app.module.ts I have

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
```

process.env.SECRET_KEY is undefined in node_modules file (console.log(process.env.SECRET_KEY)), but signOptions: { expiresIn: '60m' } is defined.

If I try to write to console SECRET_KEY from .env everywhere else is defined, but in node_modules is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConfigModule`'s `ConfigService` runs `dotenv`'s `config()` method, but all decorators run at the same time, so the `config()` method is not called yet. You can use the async registration instead and use the `ConfigService` like so

```js
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
    secret: config.get('SECRET_KEY')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you Call the ConfigService in your App Module constructor :

```
 export class AppModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
}
```